# Python POST request says "Not Acceptable!"

Tags: python, web, python-requests

My school has a website that students can sign up for classes during a study period and I forget all the time. I'm trying to make a script that logs in and signs up for me. This is what I have:

```
import requests

payload = {
    "username": "",
    "pwd": "",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://www.bloomingtonsouth.org/plus/login.php', data=payload)
    print(p.text)

    r = s.get('http://www.bloomingtonsouth.org/plus/student.php')
    print(r.text)
```

The output: "Not Acceptable!

## Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Not Acceptable!

## Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

"

What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1:

```
headers = {

        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Host": "bloomingtonsouth.org",
        "Referer": "http://bloomingtonsouth.org/plus/login.php",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"

        }

url = "http://www.bloomingtonsouth.org/plus/login.php"
payload = {"username": "", "password": "", "submitted":"TRUE"}
post = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

r = requests.get('http://www.bloomingtonsouth.org/plus/student.php')
print(r.text)
```

I tried this, using the headers I found the browser using and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to check with the API owner or their documentation, it doesn't seem to be related to the `requests` library.

Comment: There are a multiple things that server may expect - `"Content-Type"` header is properly set? Also, can you also post response code? `r.status_code`. That might give some indication. If it's 403 - likely your credentials are not right, if it's something else it can then be debugged.

Comment: @gabhijit The response code is 406

Comment: if you still can't get it to work, you can workaround using selenium / headless browser, although it's more effort than requests.

Answer (score 1):

User-agent needs to be a header, not in the payload.

```
login()
def login():
    headers = headers - {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"}
    url = "http://www.bloomingtonsouth.org/plus/login.php"
    payload = {"username": "", "pwd": ""}
    post = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

try this code for logging in and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I still get "Not Acceptable!"

Comment: https://webhostingmedia.net/http-error-406-not-acceptable/ This is likely cause. The way to debug this problem is - Try to submit form through a browser and then try to get same set of headers as are sent by browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full url to login you could use this online tool that converts URL to python request:

https://curl.trillworks.com/

If you don't understand the website post full url please.